# How to understand android display framework flow?

Tags: android, graphics, hal

[image]

I have some naive question, as I have never worked with android as a whole. 
I am trying to undestand display framework of android.

Above is a picture that I saw in android display framework. I  want to understand how this flow works.

1.After status bar how can a hardware like GPU be there?

2.How can GPU be inside of surfaceflinger, while all the hardwares are only accessible through kernel drivers?

3.Is graphics HAL different than display HAL or both are same?

4.On a screen we sees different things. It can be a video, a 3d/2d game or home screen or a music player. Does all of these things uses surfaceflinger? I mean every thing that needs to be displayed have to go through surfaceflinger? They can use different ways to express their data, but ultimately to be shown, this data have to be composited via surfaceflinger, then give it to HAL?

Thanks.

Comment: To 4: That's the way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly confusing picture....

1. The Statusbar/Views etc. generate buffers with graphical data. To generate those they have to communicate via HAL with the GPU. There is no GPU in the statusbar ;)
2. The GPU here also means some communication with HAL. The Flinger composites the buffers and prepares them for the Composer
3. Well they do different thing so they sould be different?

Comment: I think there is one thing that is called hardware UI and openGL. Can those be a reason that the image is rendered before it is given to surfaceflinger? Can the status bar be using GPU that way?

Comment: I think you mean the right thing. For example harware acceleration was not supported in early versions. The UI was rendered with CPU. now its possible to render hardware accelerated. I guess thats what you mean with hardware UI. But at the end all those buffers/elements are packed together in the frame buffer which is handled by the gpu (opengl,GLES).

Comment: I have one more question/confusion/understanding problem. I have added that in P.S of the question details.